# Save plot to a matrix in Octave/MatLab

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I wish to save a plot created in octave in a matrix

```
x=[0:10];
y=[0:10];
figure(1);
plot(x,y);
```

How can I save this plot into a matrix (or a 3D array, assuming it is RGB). To explain in a different way. Lets say there exist an image "img.jpg" in the working directory. Than i can open it as a matrix

```
A=imread("img.jpg");
```

How can one accomplish the same, having the plot saved in the matrix A?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean loading an image stored as a matrix into a variable? If so, You can use
 A = load('img.mat')